# c# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+=10 WHERE moneyId='5'' at line 1

I looked for this error but I couldnt find solution.

```
public static void updateMoney(int moneyID,int quantity)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = connection.baglanti;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE moneystok SET `quantity`+=@adding where         moneyId=@id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", moneyID.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adding", quantity).ToString();
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `+=` in most SQL engines. Use `x = x+y` instead

```
UPDATE moneystok 
SET `quantity` = `quantity` + @adding 
where moneyId=@id
```

Comment: ...and use transactions!